# How to seed database table with phone numbers using SQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have table in my postgres database that I'm using to store phone numbers formatted as: `12223334444` (as a varchar).

As I know i will be working with US phone numbers only i thought it would be a good idea to pre-populate the database with all phone numbers that could be requested.  That is, all numbers from `11_111_111_111` through `19_999_999_999`.

Right now I'm achieving this by using application code and it takes a VERY long time.

Assuming I have a table named `phones` and a single column named `digits`, is there a way to populate the database using SQL?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This is a bad idea.

```
select 19999999999 - 11111111111;
```

```
8888888888
```

That's about 8.9 billion phone numbers. Don't build tables that big unless you absolutely have to. Tables that big severely affect transaction logs, index size, backup size and time to complete, etc.

But, if you need to generate and load a lot of data like this for PostgreSQL, there are two sensible ways to do it.

Steps depend on whether you generate the data using PostgreSQL or using application code.

For PostgreSQL, in a transaction,

- drop all the indexes and constraints,
- generate and insert the data
- create all the indexes and constraints, and
- commit the transaction.

Inserting great amounts of data is a lot faster if you commit, say, 10k rows at a time. Experiment. If you do that, you'll need to adjust the transaction boundaries in those steps above. (Each of those steps becomes one or more transactions.)

If you go with application code, it's usually fastest to

- generate a csv file using application code,
- drop all the indexes and constraints,
- load the csv file with COPY,
- create all the indexes and constraints.

Answer (score 1):

This is a crazy question, but postgres has an answer

```
SELECT generate_series(1,19999999999)
```

This will create a table with all numbers between 1 and 19999999999

```
 INSERT INTO phone_table(phone number) 
 SELECT LPAD(g::VARCHAR(12),10,'0') FROM generate_series(1,19999999999) AS g;
```

This will still take a long time, but it will probably be faster than application code.

Comment: You could start at 11111111111 and I guess you are missing a value for phone.